# Subtracting value over multiple cells

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, cumulative-sum

I am trying to build a spreadsheet that keeps track of my inventory. I want to use the First In First Out approach and need the formula to solve the following problem. I want to subtract the value 16 from the list of stocks over multiple rows.

```
Value= 16

Column A    -->   Column B
  10                 0
  5                  0
  2                  1
  3                  3
  12                12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample below:

- **Subtract:** B2 = number [16]
- **Subtract:** B3 = formula `=B2-A2`. Copy down.
- **Out:** C2 = formula `=IF(B2>A2,0,IF(B2>0,A2-B2,A2))`. Copy down.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

delete everything in B column and use this ArrayFormula like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
 IF(IF(A4:A="", ,{B1; (SUMIF(ROW(A4:A), "<="&ROW(A4:A), A4:A)-B1)*-1})>A4:A, 0, 
 IF(IF(A4:A="", ,{B1; (SUMIF(ROW(A4:A), "<="&ROW(A4:A), A4:A)-B1)*-1})>0, A4:A-
    IF(A4:A="", ,{B1; (SUMIF(ROW(A4:A), "<="&ROW(A4:A), A4:A)-B1)*-1}), A4:A)))
```

[image: 0]